# How do i turn my Sub into a Function?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, function

```
Option Explicit
Private objFSO As New FileSystemObject

Sub GetDirectory()

Dim WorkbookDir As String


    WorkbookDir = ThisWorkbook.Path


    ' Check wether file exists



        ' Assume that the file does not exist and is not writeable to begin with
    Dim fileIsGood As Boolean
    Dim fileObject As Object

    ' Look for the log file path and make sure that it exists
    If objFSO.FileExists(WorkbookDir) Then

        WorkbookDir = True

    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Why would like to have a function? a `function` returns something, `sub` does not. What do you want as return value?

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: Should be VisualBasic @Juhana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Option Explicit
Private objFSO As New FileSystemObject

Function GetDirectory() as Boolean

Dim WorkbookDir As String


WorkbookDir = ThisWorkbook.Path


' Check wether file exists



    ' Assume that the file does not exist and is not writeable to begin with
Dim fileIsGood As Boolean
Dim fileObject As Object

' Look for the log file path and make sure that it exists
If objFSO.FileExists(WorkbookDir) Then

    WorkbookDir = True

End If

return WorkBookDir

End Function
```